# Widget ID Name Clashes in Android Layouts

Tags: android, layout, android-widget, android-resources

In my current project, I have three different `EditText` widgets, in three different `Activity` layouts, which are used to input a year. I started by creating the UI and originally had

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/year_text" ... other attributes ... />
```

in each of my XML layout files. I never had any compiler errors due to this name clash and only realized that it might be a problem as I started to implement the behavior behind the UI for each `Activity`. So my first question is whether or not this kind of name clash will lead to problems down the road?

From what I understand, the `+` tells the layout parser to create a new value for the named ID in the `R.java` file. I can also reference a previously given ID using the `@id/name` syntax. What happens if I remove the `+` from all of my `EditText`s but one? This solves the problem of allocating a new value for the identifier in the `R` class. But will reusing the same ID inside different layouts cause any problems? (Recall that the name clashes are across different XML layout files, not within the same layout.)

For now, I have created long names for all of my widget IDs. For example:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/details_year_text" ... other attributes ... />
<EditText android:id="@+id/year_filter_year_text" ... other attributes ... />
<EditText android:id="@+id/year_and_number_filter_year_text" ... other attributes ... />
```

The prefix follows the name of the XML layout file where each `EditText` lives. This gets a little bit cumbersome, especially when using the autocomplete feature in NetBeans. (Yes, I'm using NetBeans rather than Eclipse. =p). If I do in fact need to use unique names for each of my `EditText` widgets, it would be handy to separate them into namespaces. Does the XML layout support any syntax which will create inner classes of `R.id` which can serve as namespaces for my IDs?

Finally, I know this is a very small project. I can imagine there are Android apps with a lot more widgets than I am using. What is the standard practice, if any, for naming and organizing IDs in the XML layouts of a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, android provides id tag for your resources xml file, which means you can declare your id first ( similar to string ), here is the information that might help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id